# Delay for Simple HTML DOM Class

Tags: php, html, ajax, parsing, dom

I'm using the simple html dom class and have gotten it to work on basic pages and can view the information I want. However, when I attempt to use it on a page that reloads a div with ajax, I can't seem to get it to "wait" before reading the page.

I basically want it to load the page, then wait 2 seconds before reading the page content (so that the new div has time to load). Is this possible or am I trying to use the class incorrectly? I'm manually inputting the URL, so it's not a link issue.

[Example Page](http://www.move.com/apartmentsforrent-search/los-angeles_ca#/pg-2): 
 - You can see the load issue when you navigate through the pages.

Someone suggested curl and I tried that with the same results.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The DOM class does not parse or execute Javascript, so the AJAX loaded content will never be available to it no matter how long you wait. What you want to do might as well be impossible using PHP. If the data you want is coming from the AJAX request, you would need to make the AJAX request from PHP, instead of loading the parent page.

Answer (score 1):

PHP runs on the server.  JavaScript (e.g. AJAX) runs in the browser, after the PHP code on the server has finished producing the page.  You can't make a PHP program, running on the server, wait for an event that happens later in the browser.

You'll need to either load the content for that div using PHP code, or replace the PHP DOM-parsing code with JavaScript code that does the work on the client.

Comment: Have any good suggestions where I can find a javascript class that does that? =)

Comment: @MichaelLuyties, well, you don't actually have to parse the HTML when you use JavaScript, because the browser does that for you.  jQuery can be useful for looking up the DOM objects that you want to manipulate.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Sleep method ( http://php.net/manual/en/function.sleep.php ) if you simply want to delay the program execution for some set amount of time.